# How to apply Conv1D after Dense or Flatten layers: ValueError: Shapes (1, 1, 3) and (1, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can apply conv1D layer after a dense or flatten layer?

It gives error as:

> ValueError: Shapes (1, 1, 3) and (1, 1) are incompatible.

**The data set is not a time series.**  Please do not suggest to change the positions of the layers. Input data has 1000 lines and 50 features. output y is multi-category [0,1,2].

Here is an example code:

```
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 1

x=np.random.randint(-10,10,(1000,50,1)).astype(float)
y=np.random.randint(0,3,(1000,1,1))

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=17)
train_y = to_categorical(train_y)
test_y = to_categorical(test_y)
n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_y.shape[1]
          
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_features, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))

t=time.time()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)


print(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your issue, and the problem is not with the conv1D that is applied after the Dense layer for the issue you have posted but it is with your last layer.

As you are doing multi-class classification your output layer should be the number of classes which is `3` in your case.

Also your output `train_y` and `test_y` are of `3D` shape inplace of being `2D` shape i.e `(batch_size, num_classes)`

So once you will reshape your `train_y` and `test_y` and change the `n_outputs` in the last layer it will work out for you. I am pasting the code below for convenience. I have checked the code and it is working.

```
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 1

x=np.random.randint(-10,10,(1000,50,1)).astype(float)
y=np.random.randint(0,3,(1000,1,1))

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=17)
train_y = to_categorical(train_y)
test_y = to_categorical(test_y)
n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_y.shape[1]
          
train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[2]))
print(train_y.shape)

test_y = test_y.reshape((test_y.shape[0], test_y.shape[2]))
print(test_y.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_features, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation= 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))



t=time.time()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)


print(accuracy)
```